# How to filter stream in java with few parameters?

Tags: java

I need to filter list of visits by few parameters. I know that this is not good solution. When there will be a lot of visits I can't get all of them to just get for example few of them. I was thinking about Querydsl? Anyone have good solution?
this is my method:

```
private List<Visit> findVisitByParameters(CustomSearchCommand visit){
List<Visit> allVisits = repository.findAll();
List<Visit> visitList = allVisits.stream()
        .filter(v -> v.getDate().isAfter(visit.getDateFrom()))
        .filter(v -> v.getDate().isBefore(visit.getDateTo()))
        .filter(v -> v.getVeterinarian().getAnimalType().equals(visit.getAnimalType()))
        .filter(v -> v.getVeterinarian().getMedicalSpecialization().equals(visit.getMedicalSpecialization()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
if(visitList.isEmpty()) throw new InvalidParameterException("There are not any visits in this time period with" +
        " this animal type and medical Specialization");
return visitList;
```

}

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Where is the problem? What's the output you expect and what you are getting instead? Do you only want to do this in a more compact way? If all you want to do is reduce the `filter()` operations, I would suggest adding `visit.animalType` and `visit.medicalSpecialization` to your query or setting up a `Predicate` to validate the dates.

Comment: @JettoMartínez I think the problem is that a query is done to the database that returns all results, and only after that filtering occurs. If database has many rows this is a wast of resources, when filtering can be done in first place in the repository query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [QueryDsl](http://querydsl.com/), [Jooq](http://www.jooq.org/), [Spring Data](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data), [hibernate](https://hibernate.org/), etc to do that.

Example of using Spring Data:

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.status = ?1 and u.name = ?2")
User findUserByStatusAndName(Integer status, String name);
```

Example taken from: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query